# method throws exception rather then returning Try in for comprehension

Tags: scala, validation, for-loop, error-handling, try-catch

Please find below sample source code, that returns :-

> website home page, when auth service is not available,
>
> default home page, when auth service available, but page service is
>   not available,
>
> error page, when both services are not available,
>
> user page, when all services are available

```
package tryeg

import scala.util._

/**
  * Created by mogli on 6/6/17.
  */
class TrySample(val service : TryService) {

  def homePageForUser(userId: String, secret: String): Try[Page] = {
    val tryhomepage = for {
      user     <- service.authenticate(userId, secret)
      homePage <- service.fetchHomePage(user)
    } yield homePage

    tryhomepage match {
      case Failure(e: ServiceUnavailableException) =>
        e.service match{
          case "AuthService" =>
            Try(WebsiteHomePage)
          case "PageService" =>
            Try(DefaultHomePage)
          case _ =>
            Try(ErrorPage)

        }

      case _ =>
        tryhomepage
    }
  }
}

case class User(id: Long)

case class Page(title: String, content: String)
object DefaultHomePage extends Page("Welcome!", "This is your amazing Homepage!")
object WebsiteHomePage extends Page("Welcome!", "This is your amazing website")
object ErrorPage extends Page("Sorry!", "Unhandled Erro")


sealed class MyException(msg: String) extends Exception(msg, null)
case class UnknownUserException(userId: Long) extends MyException(s"User with id [$userId] is unknown.")
case class WrongSecretException(userId: Long) extends MyException(s"User with id [$userId] provided the wrong secret.")
case class ServiceUnavailableException(service: String) extends MyException(s"The Service [$service] is currently unavailable")


trait TryService {
  def authenticate(userId: String, secret: String): Try[User]
  def fetchHomePage(user: User): Try[Page]
}
```

Also, find below the sample unit test cases :-

```
package tryeg

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

import scala.util.Try


/**
  * Created by mogli on 6/6/17.
  */
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TrySampleTest extends FlatSpecLike with MockFactory{

  val user = User(123)
  val tryuser = Try(user)
  val userpage = Page("jbaba", "jbaba ka page")
  val tryuserpage = Try(userpage)

  "non happy path with authentication service not available" should "return website page" in {
    val service = stub[TryService]
    ( service.authenticate(_, _) ).when("123", "secret") throws ServiceUnavailableException("AuthService")
    val trySample = new TrySample(service)
    val page = trySample.homePageForUser("123", "secret")
    //page should be (Try(WebsiteHomePage))
    println("non happy path for authentication service down ")
  }

  "non happy path with page service not available" should "return default home page" in {
    val service = stub[TryService]
    ( service.authenticate(_, _) ).when("123", "secret") returns (tryuser)
    ( service.fetchHomePage(_) ).when(user) throws ServiceUnavailableException("PageService")
    val trySample = new TrySample(service)
    val page = trySample.homePageForUser("123", "secret")
    //page should be (Try(DefaultHomePage))
    println("non happy path for page service down ")
  }

}
```

Now, the first test case is throwing below exception, but the expected result was Try(WebsiteHomePage)

```
tryeg.ServiceUnavailableException: The Service [AuthService] is currently unavailable

    at tryeg.TrySampleTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(TrySampleTest.scala:31)
    at tryeg.TrySampleTest$$anonfun$1.apply(TrySampleTest.scala:29)
    at tryeg.TrySampleTest$$anonfun$1.apply(TrySampleTest.scala:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TryService` stub is throwing an exception instead of returning a `Failure`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my second test case is working as expected.

Comment: `map` and `flatMap` of `Try` will catch exceptions and turn them into failures.  But the call to `service.authenticate` is not inside a `map` or `flatMap` (think about how the for comprehension gets translated to `flatMap` and `map`), so any exception it throws will propagate out of `homePageForUser`.